# Cant get Alpha Vantage to work Python? No module named 'alpha_vantage'

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alpha_vantage'

line 22, in 
from alpha_vantage.fundamentaldata import FundamentalData

I have Alpha Vantage installed using pip install alpha-vantage that didnt fix the problem so then I tried pip install alpha_vantage and that didnt fix it either.

I am a python noob, just following a tutorial online for python finance to learn.

Comment: If you aren’t exactly sure what you’re installing, you probably should stop what you’re doing. Installing dependencies blindly without having ANY semblance of an idea what they are or what they contain is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Could you help me then?

Comment: The module is named `alpha_vantage` so that is what you need to install. You need to ensure that pip is installing the module WHERE python will look for modules ie directories being used. There are plenty of on-line resources helping to sort his out: just search around this topic.

Comment: I believe the issue is that it’s installing the module as alpha-vantage. Found this out when doing pip list